# How to create a callable method/function in PHP

Tags: php, parallel-processing, amphp

I'm trying to achieve multitasking in PHP.
At the moment I'm evaluating [AMPHP](https://www.amphp.org)   framework, and in particular paralell and paralel-functions.

But I can't figure how is to create a method callable...

The idea is that I will have a Class with some methods
and I want to instantiate multiples objects, and invoque, for each one, the same method, but in paralell, or asynchronously.

I found a TestCase in parallel-functions folder, and I can't figure out what is doing

```
public function testClassInstanceMethod() {
    $instance = new TestCallables;

    $callable = [$instance, 'instanceMethod'];
    $result = $callable(1);  //<-- what is (1)?
    $callable = parallel($callable);

    $this->assertSame($result, Promise\wait($callable(1)));
}
```

What happened if I create multiples instances?

```
$instances[] = new TestCallables;
```

I think that what I need to know first is how to create a callable class/method/function... in PHP.

> Important information: This should run in web environment ( no
>   pThreads !) in Yii Framework.

Any suggestions?
Best Regards

Comment: Your title is confusing because every method/function is in essence callable.

Comment: In the example, 1 would be the argument to the method `instanceMethod` on the object in `$instance`.

Comment: Hi @Daan , I'm trying to use this https://amphp.org/parallel-functions/ ...

Comment: Another idea of what I try to do is this: https://github.com/amphp/parallel but instead of "file_get_contents" function, I want to call a method in a class!, of course I willl need to pass parameters and return values!

Answer (score 0):

Data is passed between the treads/processes in serialized form, so you can't just instantiate an object in one thread/process and call the same instance's method in another thread.

I need more information to help you; your question is confusing a bit. Please show the example that doesn't work - and I'll help you to understand, why.